# Transactional email invoice Qty column too far left

Tags: transactional-mail, ce-1.9.2.2

Small problem but bugging me. Transactional email invoice quantity column too far left causing pricing not to line up. View in outlook, iphone email & gmail all look off but android email on phone looks fine with columns all lining up.
Driving me crazy.  Thanks  - **Update**, noticing the blue box/cell with shipping, tax and final total might have to go across whole page which would push over line items. In email order view, that cell/box shows across the invoice bottom. 
[image]

Comment: So what do you want to archive , this is a CSS issue i can be solved by editing the email template

Comment: Above invoice shows perfect in android phone email but not on android tablet email, outlook or iphone email. Any reason you can think of to explain that or still CSS issue @VishwasBhatnagar ? Thanks for responding earlier.

Comment: I found that if I altered: {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
to this: {{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
It works but wonder if that affects anything not wanted? @VishwasBhatnagar
I appreciate your input. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked some of my transactional mails and came across the same as you mentioned in your comment

When changing

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_invoice_items" 
invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

to this:

```
{{layout area="frontend" handle="sales_email_order_items" invoice=$invoice order=$order}}
```

I haven´t realized any issues which this change would effect.